# How to filter out rows that do not fit specified condition in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame (ID  = c(1:20),
                  Ethnicity = c(rep(c("White", "Asian", "Black", "Hispanic", "Other"), times=20/5)),
                  Age = c(1:20),
                  Set = rep(c(1,2,3,4), times=20/4)
)
```

Is there a way to filter out all the rows where `Ethnicity` is NOT Asian using the `filter` function in R? Maybe something similar to `-filter`?

Thanks!

Comment: Try: `dplyr::filter(df, Ethnicity != "Asian")`

Comment: Clarity: *"`filter` function in R"* might be interpreted as `base::filter`, which is far different from `dplyr::filter`; that particular name-collision is a source of problem for many new to R who are learning primarily/solely dplyr syntax.

Comment: From this question it seems it would be useful for you to go through some R tutorials to include "conditionals" (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, etc), as what you're asking is common to everywhere any conditional can be used (regardless of base/dplyr/data.table). While not a tutorial, simply [`?Comparison`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Comparison.html) (also `?==`, `?!=`, etc) as well as [`?Ops`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/groupGeneric.html) might be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to PaulS's tidyverse/dplyr solution, here's how you can filter out rows using base R.

```
df[df$Ethnicity != "Asian",]

#>    ID Ethnicity Age Set
#> 1   1     White   1   1
#> 3   3     Black   3   3
#> 4   4  Hispanic   4   4
#> 5   5     Other   5   1
#> 6   6     White   6   2
#> 8   8     Black   8   4
#> 9   9  Hispanic   9   1
#> 10 10     Other  10   2
#> 11 11     White  11   3
#> 13 13     Black  13   1
#> 14 14  Hispanic  14   2
#> 15 15     Other  15   3
#> 16 16     White  16   4
#> 18 18     Black  18   2
#> 19 19  Hispanic  19   3
#> 20 20     Other  20   4
```